# MySQL. Update table all rows for specific columns by subquery that takes input value from each row

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is a challenge: 
I have three tables.
I need to populate table_1 with the result of a query.
The input to this query is the id of the table_1. How can I do this?

Thank you.

I already tried

```
UPDATE  table_1 AS a 
           INNER JOIN
           (
               SELECT  s.some_name 
               FROM    table_2 as st
               JOIN table_3 AS s ON s.a_id = st.a_id 
               ORDER BY st.somefiled DESC
               LIMIT 1 
           ) AS b ON  a.a_id = b.a_id AND a.t_id = b.t_id 
           SET     a.some_name = b.some_name
```

But this gives me error

> 1054 - Unknown column 'b.a_id' in 'on clause'
>   Although, a_id exists in table_2 and in table_3

Thank you in advance

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1. In this case, that might be an example of how the table should look before and after the query.

Comment: You have to speicfy the Id column in select list as well.

Comment: @Strawberry thanks for your help. I think Ankit is already answered the question.

Comment: You're entitled to your point of view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to speicfy the Id columns in select list as well. Somthing like this:-

```
UPDATE  table_1 AS a 
       INNER JOIN
       (
           SELECT  s.some_name, st.a_id, st.t_id
           FROM    table_2 as st
           JOIN table_3 AS s ON s.a_id = st.a_id 
           ORDER BY st.somefiled DESC
           LIMIT 1 
       ) AS b ON  a.a_id = b.a_id AND a.t_id = b.t_id 
       SET     a.some_name = b.some_name
```

I dont know whether this solves your purpose or not. But this will remove the error

Comment: Seems to work. The only thing that it shows now  `3 - Error writing file '/tmp/MYMN0O77' (Errcode: 28 - No space left on device)`. So I can not finilize the query still ((( And this is so even if I have only 1 line in table_1